# How to add an automatic refresh in Wordpress for a Page/Post or an embedded OneDrive/Excel HTML Code?

Tags: plugins, shortcode, code

I have added an embedded Excel sheet on my website's home page. It is always displaying live data which is changing all the time. But when me or my colleagues view that page, they need to refresh the page every second themselves to view the changed data in the Excel sheet.

**I think there are two ways to do it:**

1. Either to edit the embedded Excel/OneDrive code and put an automatic 1-second refresh in it.
2. Or to maybe install a plugin and add some code in the `header.php` to refresh the whole page after 1-second.

But the problem is, I don't know how to do either of them and I've searched the whole internet but can't seem to find a way. I would love it if anyone could help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this little function below will help you out.
It will add, on the front-page *(and/or home page)*, automatically a meta element, which will take care for a page refresh after a given time interval. *(10 seconds in the example below)*
I wouldn't set the time shorter then 3 seconds but that is up to you.

> > Please backup `functions.php` first before adding below code into it.

```
/**
 * Auto add a page refresh into <head> for Home and/or Front page
 * 
 * Info {@link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh}
 *      {@link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/}
 *      {@link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/}
 *      {@link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/}
 *      
 * @since WordPress @version 1.5.0
 * Checked functionality with WordPress @version 5.5.1
 */
 add_action( "wp_head", "add_meta_refresh_timer_wpse374042" );
 function add_meta_refresh_timer_wpse374042() { 
     // Change/Remove to own preference
     if( is_front_page() || is_home() ) 
    {
        echo "<!-- Auto refresh --> \n";
        // Adjust amount of seconds to own preference
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"10\" />";
    }
}
```

Good luck.